# How to edit text in specific tags in specified files to capitalize the content

Tags: command-line, text

Ubuntu 20.04 desktop

A directory contains files with different extensions.

Some of the files have the extension .nfo. They contain metadata about video files for the Kodi system.

These .nfo files contain structured text under the header `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>`

The text in the files may contain one, two or all three of the following tags:

```
<title>Some example text</title>
<showtitle>Some example text</showtitle>
<originaltitle>Some example text</originaltitle>
```

Is there a command (or script) that will:

Find these tags in the .nfo files in the directory. If they exist and contain text, capitalise the first letter of each word contained in each tag, and update the same file with the edited content.

?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Linux (and version) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `.ngo` files are XML, probably the right way to do this is using an XML tool such as `xmlstarlet` to transform your data according to a suitable XLST template.

However if you just need something quick'n'dirty then maybe with Perl:

```
perl -lpe 's@(?<=<title>)(.*)(?=</title>)@join " ", map { ucfirst $_ } split(/\s+/,$1)@e'
```

Ex. given the following `file.ngo` based on the [Kodi template movie .nfo file](https://kodi.wiki/view/NFO_files/Movies#Template_nfo)

```
$ cat file.nfo
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<movie>
    <title>Some example text</title>
    <showtitle>Some example text</showtitle>
    <originaltitle>Some example text</originaltitle>
    <userrating>0</userrating>
    <outline></outline>
    <plot></plot>
    <tagline></tagline>
    <runtime></runtime>
    <mpaa></mpaa>
    <uniqueid type="" default="true"></uniqueid>
    <genre></genre>
    <country></country>
    <credits></credits>
    <director></director>
    <premiered></premiered>
    <studio></studio>
    <actor>
        <name></name>
        <role></role>
        <order></order>
        <thumb></thumb>
    </actor>
</movie>
```

then

```
$ perl -lpe 's@(?<=<title>)(.*)(?=</title>)@join " ", map { ucfirst $_ } split(/\s+/,$1)@e' file.nfo
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<movie>
    <title>Some Example Text</title>
    <showtitle>Some example text</showtitle>
    <originaltitle>Some example text</originaltitle>
    <userrating>0</userrating>
    <outline></outline>
    <plot></plot>
    <tagline></tagline>
    <runtime></runtime>
    <mpaa></mpaa>
    <uniqueid type="" default="true"></uniqueid>
    <genre></genre>
    <country></country>
    <credits></credits>
    <director></director>
    <premiered></premiered>
    <studio></studio>
    <actor>
        <name></name>
        <role></role>
        <order></order>
        <thumb></thumb>
    </actor>
</movie>
```

Comment: Thanks - this displays as I originally asked, but I was really looking for the command to edit and save the changed files. I've updated my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @4n3wv with `perl`, you can use the `-i` switch to edit files in-place. See for example [7 of the most useful Perl command line options](https://perlmaven.com/perl-command-line-options)

Comment: that's it! Thanks so much, you've saved me a bunch of tedious editing time. The final command I used is: ```perl -i -p -l -e 's@(?<=<title>)(.*)(?=</title>)@join " ", map { ucfirst $_ } split(/\s+/,$1)@e' *.nfo```